# how do I grep in R?

Tags: r, subset

I would like to choose rows based on the subsets of their names, for example

If I have the following data:

```
data <- structure(c(91, 92, 108, 104, 87, 91, 91, 97, 81, 98), 
.Names = c("fee-", "fi", "fo-", "fum-", "foo-", "foo1234-", "123foo-", 
"fum-", "fum-", "fum-"))
```

how do I select the rows matching 'foo'?

using grep() doesn't work:

```
 grep('foo', data)
```

returns:

```
integer(0)
```

what am I doing wrong? or, is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to grep the names property of data, not the values property.

For your example, use

```
> grep("foo",names(data))
[1] 5 6 7
> data[grep("foo",names(data))]
  foo- foo1234-  123foo- 
  87       91       91
```

One other clean way to do this is using data frames.

```
> data <- data.frame(values=c(91, 92, 108, 104, 87, 91, 91, 97, 81, 98), 
                   names = c("fee-", "fi", "fo-", "fum-", "foo-", "foo1234-", "123foo-", 
                   "fum-", "fum-", "fum-"))

> data$values[grep("foo",data$names)]
[1] 87 91 91
```

Answer (score 6):

Use subset in combination with regular expressions:

```
subset(your_data, regexpr("foo", your_data$your_column_to_match) > 0))
```

If you just care about a dataset with one column I guess you do not need to specify a column name...

Philip

Comment: I usually find `grepl` to be more useful here -- you can skip the comparison vs 0 thing, which makes the code look a little cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

```
> grep("foo",names(data), value=T)
[1] "foo-"     "foo1234-" "123foo-"
```

if value is true, it returns the content instead of the index