# Loop over list of strings printing string starting with x

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe (df) with a column of type strings such as

```
code     country
DK       Denmark
DE       Germany
BEB      Belgium
B        Brazil
```

And I wont to write a for loop that prints the countries starting with B. This is how I approach it but I get an error:

```
for (i in unique(df$country)) {
  if (i == grep("^B", unique(df$country), value = TRUE)) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Error in if (i == grep("^B", unique(df$country), value = TRUE)) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I grep in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220631/how-do-i-grep-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need a loop here as `grep` is vectorized

```
unique(subset(df, grepl("^B", country), select = country))
```

-output

```
  country
3 Belgium
4  Brazil
```

---

Regarding the issue in the loop, it is just that `==` does elementwise comparison and returns the logical vector with the length of the second vector as the first one is just of length 1.

```
'Belgium' == grep("^B", unique(df$country), value = TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

and this triggers the length warning as `if/else` expects a vector of length 1 as input

If we use `%in%`, it returns a single TRUE/FALSE

```
for (i in unique(df$country)) {
  if (i %in% grep("^B", unique(df$country), value = TRUE)) {
    print(i)
  }
}
```

-output

```
[1] "Belgium"
[1] "Brazil"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(code = c("DK", "DE", "BEB", "B"), country = c("Denmark", 
"Germany", "Belgium", "Brazil")), class = "data.frame",
 row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```